# Build JAR file with only recursivly dependant classes from main class

Tags: jar, pack

is there a simple way to generate a JAR file, that contains only the classes that depend transitive from a certain "main" class (reflection omitted of course). 
I want to provide a little part of my application to someone else but do not want to export the whole application.

Thanks,
M.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest approach is using a tool like yGuard which "...provides elaborate code shrinking functionality through dependency analysis." This would also solve the same problem where you give it an entry point, and it performs dependency analysis to work out which classes can be excluded from the Jar.

However, I have throught about this problem myself a few times and fancied having a go at it myself for the challenge. All it would take would be to parse the import statements of Java source files and build a dependncy graph of how the classes interact with each other. Each reference from the main class should be recursively scanned until a complete graph is assembled. Then once the graph is assembled it would be a case of outputting this in a way that some packaging logic could process (or if you are feeling daring, the JDK has its own built in Jar creating/modifying code to do it yourself). Granted, this approach would require writing this custom utility and would also miss fully qualified class references in the code.